# How to store gps values in EEPROM arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, tinygps, eeprom

I have two successfully working individual programs,
**1.GPS coordinate extract program.**
**2.EEPROM saving and reading program.**
now all I want to do is combine them both, whenever GPS location is updated ,I want to save that latitude data to EEPROM memory repalcing the previously saved data, but I guess my program is unable to save it,its just showing blank spaces when reading EEPROM,please help me guys..here is my code.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> 
#include <TinyGPS++.h>
#define RXPin 8
#define TXPin 9
#define GPSBaud 9600
#define ConsoleBaud 9600

// The serial connection to the GPS device
SoftwareSerial ss(RXPin, TXPin);

// The TinyGPS++ object
TinyGPSPlus gps;
#include <EEPROM.h>
int address = 0; 
int read_value = 0; 
char data;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(ConsoleBaud);
  ss.begin(GPSBaud);
  Serial.println("Previous value stored :");
  for(address = 0; address < 25; address ++)        // read the entire EEPROM memory
  {  
    read_value = EEPROM.read(address);
    Serial.write(read_value);
  }
  Serial.println("\n");

}

void loop()
{

  while (ss.available() > 0)
    gps.encode(ss.read());

  if (gps.location.isUpdated() || gps.altitude.isUpdated())
  {
    Serial.print("Location: "); 
    Serial.print(gps.location.lat(), 6);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(gps.location.lng(), 6);
    Serial.println("\n");

    data=(gps.location.lat(), 6);

    for(address = 0; address < 25;  )
    {
      EEPROM.write(address, data); 
      address ++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `data=(gps.location.lat(), 6);` just always stores `6` in `data`, this is what will be sotored on all 25 first locations of EEPROM. It looks you don't understand what you're doing with this code. I'd recommend taking a look at some basic C programming tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Consider TinyGPS++ over TinyGPS only if you are running on Due or processor which can take advantage of the higher precision of 64-bit “double” floating-point.

`char data;` should be `double data;`. You're wasting resources otherwise.

`data=(gps.location.lat(), 6);` isn't how you do it. You only need to specify precision when writing to `Serial`, like `Serial.print(gps.location.lat(), 6);`. Make it `data = gps.location.lat();`.

`address ++;` should be `address = address <=512-sizeof(address) ? (address + sizeof(data)): 0 ;`

`address <=512-sizeof(address)` ensures that the last value written to the `EEPROM` is written in it's entirety.

Alternatively, I would recommend [this](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/EEPROMWriteAnything) to save you data structure directly to `EEPROM`, and what @jfpoilpret mentions.

Answer (score 1):

You might try using `sprintf`. First define a buffer:

```
char data[25];
```

Then use `sprintf` to print to the buffer:

```
sprintf(data, "Location: %.3f,%.3f\n", gps.location.lat(), gps.location.lon());
```

`%.3f` prints a float with 3 decimal places. Check out the [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) reference for details.

Then write the buffer to EEPROM:

```
for(address = 0; address < 25; address++ )
{
  EEPROM.write(address, data);
}
```

Comment: Careful with `lat()` and `lon()`: those return a `double` not an `int`! Hence `sprintf("...%d...")` will not work unless you explicitly cast `lat()` and `lon()` return to `int`.

Comment: well spotted @jfpoilpret :P